# JUnit Cucumber Runner not finding tests

Tags: java, cucumber, appium, cucumber-junit, appium-java

Any one know why when I run `mvn clean test -Dos=android` it doesn't find any tests to run? It runs find if I use the built in Cucumber or JUnit runner in Intellij. I am using Appium and Java 8.

Here are my files and folder structure

[image: Folder Structure]

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>App</groupId>
    <artifactId>Mobile-Automation</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>8.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>26.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>7.10.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

CucumberTestRunner.java

```java
package runner;


import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "classpath:features", glue = {"stepdefs"}, plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-html-report.html"})
public class CucumberTestRunner {
    public CucumberTestRunner(String[] args){}

}
```

TestBase.java

```java
package runner;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import pageobjects.LoginPage;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Properties;

public class TestBase {

    public static AppiumDriver driver;
    public static LoginPage loginPage;
    static Properties props = new Properties();

    public static void androidSetUp() throws MalformedURLException {
        try (InputStream inputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("decivecapabilities.properties")){
            props.load(inputStream);
        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        DesiredCapabilities androidCaps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        androidCaps.setCapability("deviceName", props.getProperty("android.capability.deviceName"));
        androidCaps.setCapability("udid", props.getProperty("android.capability.udid"));
        androidCaps.setCapability("platformName", props.getProperty("android.capability.platformName"));
        androidCaps.setCapability("platformVersion", props.getProperty("android.capability.platformVersion"));
        androidCaps.setCapability("automationName", props.getProperty("android.capability.automationName"));
        androidCaps.setCapability("appPackage", props.getProperty("android.capability.appPackage"));
        androidCaps.setCapability("appActivity", props.getProperty("android.capability.appActivity"));

        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), androidCaps);
    }

    public static void iosSetUp() throws MalformedURLException {
        try (InputStream inputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("decivecapabilities.properties")){
            props.load(inputStream);
        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        DesiredCapabilities iosCaps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        iosCaps.setCapability("deviceName", props.getProperty("ios.capability.deviceName"));
        iosCaps.setCapability("udid", props.getProperty("ios.capability.udid"));
        iosCaps.setCapability("platformName", props.getProperty("ios.capability.platformName"));
        iosCaps.setCapability("platformVersion", props.getProperty("ios.capability.platformVersion"));
        iosCaps.setCapability("automationName", props.getProperty("ios.capability.automationName"));
        //iosCaps.setCapability("app", "app-path");

        driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), iosCaps);


    }

    public static void pageObjectInit(){
        loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
    }

    public static void tearDown(){
        if (driver != null){
            driver.quit();
        }

    }
}
```

Any insight is appreciated, and I can add post more files if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By default, the Surefire Plugin will automatically include all test classes with the following wildcard patterns:
>
> - `**/Test*.java` - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that start with "Test".
> - `**/*Test.java` - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Test".
> - `**/*Tests.java` - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Tests".
> - `**/*TestCase.java` - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "TestCase".
>
> https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

By convention tests executed by Maven should end with "Test". So your class should be named `RunCucumberTest`.